# Django CMS -> upload file on gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-cms

I have problem with uploading a file ie.image.

I using NGINX and gunicorn. 
When I try upload, I get a 500 error.

I've tried many examples but I really don't know how do this.
Maybe this issue is similar, but I don't know how use this [link](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#javascript-errors)

Please help.

I create server used this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn).
Here is image with error from console: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
Here is image from start gunicorn with debug option:
[image]

gunicorn_config.py

```
command = '/opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/myenv/strona_tapicerska'
bind = '5.196.28.65:8001'
workers = 3
user = 'nobody'
```

file from /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
        server_name 5.196.28.65;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
            root /opt/myenv/strona_tapicerska/static/;
        }

       location /media/ {
        root /opt/myenv/strona_tapicerska/media/;
           }


    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov) {
      access_log   off;                                                                                                              
      expires      30d;
    }

            client_max_body_size 25M;

    location /admin/media{

    root /opt/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;}

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


   add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the permissions for where you are trying to upload?

Comment: SOLUTION: The issue was in Pillow. I changed all permissions into 777 but nothing changed.  Then I update this pack. Pillow has problems with creating thumb. Also i update django and django-cms. The last thing - in gunicorn_config I replaced user='nobody' with user in my server. Ie. user='root' etc.

Comment: Sounds unsafe though. Make sure you don't leave anything 777 or running as root

Comment: Now this permissions are useless :) Only need update pillow. About root is only example. Safest is to not use root.